# Do serverfault like questions specific to Drupal belong here?

Tags: discussion

I need feedback on some *Apache* server and *PHP* performance tuning specific for a Drupal installation, is it ok to post this kind of questions here, or do they belong to serverfault.com ?

I know I may get more attention from knowledgeable system administrators in serverfault but I really want to formulate questions that are tightly tied to Drupal but system related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the question is along the lines of

> This is my configuration, does it look ok for a Drupal site?

then it's definitely not on-topic for Drupal Answers (and probably not for Serverfault to be honest, the only site on the SE network that allows questions asking for reviews of their work is Code Review).

It's just my opinion but I don't think server tuning questions belong here; you should be considering your performance tuning without even thinking about Drupal. Load test and profile your server as if your site were built on *any* application framework and identify potential bottlenecks.

If those can then be tied specifically back to an issue in Drupal, that's when a question becomes more on topic for this site. But the important word there is *specific*. A question like

> I've profiled Drupal and it's slow, what can I do to fix my server?

will be closed very quickly.

A question like

> Drupal writes heavy cache strings to the database causing excess load, what can be done to mitigate that?

for example, would stand a better chance of being well received, assuming of course you include what research you've done and what you've tried already yourself, etc.

TL;DR If your question is about server tuning, it's going need to be a very specific situation, and not related to the performance of the server as a whole, and you're going to need to be able to justify it being heavily related to Drupal

Comment: This answer explains perfectly the genre of questions that should be asked on Drupal Answers.